# Regex to find some .php files

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to make an exclusion regex for a crawler. I want to index all the `.php` files that appear in the `/archives/` directory, but not anywhere else. So the regex should match all `.php` files, except those that are in an `/archives/` directory (however deeply nested).  So, for example, it will index

```
www.mysite.com/archives/123qwe/index.php
```

but not

```
www.mysite.com/123qwe/index.php
```

I believe this regex should work: `(?<!\/archives\/.*)\.php$`

However, I'm not able to use the `<` character, because I need to submit the regex into a web form that sanitizes `<`'s from the input. And using `&lt;` breaks the regex. So is there another way to form this regex, without needing the `<`?

Comment: This question is not about regexp per se, it is about form serialization.

Comment: I'm looking for an alternative way to make my regex match. I have no control over the form, so there's no way I can use the <.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
(?!.*\/magazine\/)(?:^.*\.php$)
```

This is a negative look ahead instead your negative lookbehind. This regex should match if there is no `/magazine/` in the string and it ends with `.php`

Thats very similar to your approach, but without the `<`.

You can see it in action here on [Regexr](http://regexr.com?2tjsi)

Comment: That looks promising. I'll put it in the crawler and vote you up if it works... thanks.

Comment: Perfect. It did exactly as I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
^www\.mysite\.com(?:/(?!archives/)[^/.]+)+\.php$
```

Or, more legibly:

```
^www\.mysite\.com
(?:
  /               # After consuming the `/`...
  (?!archives/)   # if the next name isn't `archives`...
  [^/.]+          # consume it. 
)+                # Repeat as needed.
\.php$
```

When you're creating a regex and you're not sure how to proceed, lookbehinds should never be the first tool you reach for.  In fact, I tend to regard them as a last resort.  They're just not useful enough to offset the complexity they introduce.

Comment: I think I would use `^www\.mysite\.com(?:(?!/archives/)\S)+\.php$`, because it’s shorter and doesn’t need as many quantifiers.  Both of ours do still pass through `www.mysite.com/123qwe/index/archives.php`, but I think that is ok by the original specs.

Comment: Lookbehinds do seem to be a lot of trouble! I used the regex in stema's answer, but I suspect this would work also. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just be greedy and specify that you want archive in your regular expression?

```
^(\/archives\/.+?)\.php$
```

Comment: That's the opposite of what I want. My regex has to **avoid** matching /archives/....php and just match the URLs that have .php but don't have /archives/.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the confirmation - you contradicted yourself in the question. "I want to index all the .php files that appear in the /archives/ directory, but not anywhere else."